# Python multiple pattern matching from a log file

Tags: python, regex

I've got a log file with following format:

```
2016-02-18 10:01:45.423  [a-b] [one two three] [2126]
2016-02-18 10:01:45.623  [x-y] [one two three four] [123]
2016-02-18 10:01:45.823  [z-w] [one two three four-five] [0]
```

I'd like to split the fields into variables so that e.g. for the first line:

Field1 = 2016-02-18

Field2 = 10:01:45.423

Field3 = a-b

Field4 = one two three

Field5 = 2126

I'm trying to figure out how to get the two first fields as I managed to get the last 3 with the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> data = """2016-02-18 10:01:45.423  [a-b] [one two three] [2126]"""
>>> PATTERN = re.compile(r'''\[(.*?)\]''')
>>> print (PATTERN.split(data)[1::2])
['a-b', 'one two three', '2126']
>>>
```

The content of the "Field4" may vary in length and the separator between Field2 and Field3 is 2x white space.

How do I change the code above to capture each field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think using split is a good idea (although it is do-able with your existing pattern).  Why don't you simply make a regex with proper capture groups?

e.g.

```
data = r"2016-02-18 10:01:45.423  [a-b] [one two three] [2126]"
re.match(r"^([\d\-]*) ([\d:.]*)  \[(.*)\] \[(.*)\] \[(.*)\]$", data).groups()
# gives ('2016-02-18', '10:01:45.423', 'a-b', 'one two three', '2126')
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this solution.

Comment: mind giving reason for downvote? Actually this is almost the most typical way to solve such problem in real-life

Comment: Hi Adrian, if you're addressing me with your question, I didn't downvote (at least intentionally), as a matter of fact, it does not let me even vote as I don't have enough "reputation".

Comment: @user3386665 no no... don't worry, I was not addressing you.  I should have said "for whoever downvoted"  :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without regular expression also:

```
with open("your_log.log") as f:
    for x in f:
        fields = x.strip().split()
        field1, filed2, field3, field4, field5 = fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], " ".join(fields[3:-1]), fields[-1]
```

Comment: your method doesn't even work fine if there are more than 1 consecutive spaces within `[]`